# Difference between canEdit and canModifyContent

Tags: api, file, get, edit, drive

I'm using the Google Drive API to get data about a drive file with its fileID in order to tell if I can edit the file with the account that I set the credentials on the API.

However, I don't know which parameter should I use for this, the documentation for the API states that:

- capabilities.canEdit:    (boolean)   Whether the current user can edit this file.
- capabilities.canModifyContent:   (boolean)   Whether the current user can modify the content of this file

Are editing and modifying content the very same thing?